# utf8mb4 character to represent "newline" in PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, utf8mb4

I am attempting to enable display of new lines in XATAFace (PHP Front end UI for MySQL) when a database record field is displayed.  Currently UTF+000B is stored in MySQL records to represent the newline character. UTF+000B does not cause XATAFace/PHP to display the new line when the field with the UTF+000B character is displayed.

Which UTF8mb4 character does PHP7 need to be fed to display the new line? If I know which character to use I can pre-process the csv in Notepad++ and replace the VT / UTF+000B character.

MySQL Representation, see 00 0B

[image]

Notepad++ Representation, see VT
[image]

LAMPS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MySQL 5.7 PHP7 XATAFace 2.1.3 MySQL Modified for full utfmb4 support.

Comment: LF and VT are different codes -- Where did VT come from?

Comment: Am guessing VT is NotePad++ representation of U+000B.

Comment: Yes, but why use VT anywhere?